# Python rpy2 install and ImportError of undefined symbol: PC

Tags: python, cython, rpy2

I am trying install rpy2 in CentOS release 6.6 under Anaconda3 (python 2.7). When I install it with two day's struggle (python always said I didn't install Cython, however, actually, I do installed it in the system(solved: unistall Cython and then install again)). It come out another question:      **ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC**

```
File "InfiniumPurify.py", line 23, in <module>
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
File "/home/shg047/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
File "/home/shg047/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: /home/shg047/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

Python Version: Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Anaconda： Anaconda 3

Linux： TSCC

**Any suggestion to solve this problem?**

I already tried different ways, including:

```
cp /lib64/libreadline.so.6 ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.so.6
```

Comment: ?! Rpy2 does not use Cython.